# So many Duplicate :java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/Size.class

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Please Check this code, having trouble with the duplicates.
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.Occulus.UnitySample"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 24
    multiDexEnabled true

}


buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
```

How can i find Duplicate here:

dependencies

```
compile project(':googleMobileAdsPlugin')
compile project(':gvr')
compile project(':gvrpermissionsupportrelease')
compile project(':playservicesads1021')
compile project(':playservicesadslite1021')
compile project(':playservicesbase1021')
compile project(':playservicesclearcut1021')
compile project(':playservicesgass1021')
compile project(':playservicestasks1021')
compile project(':supportv42400')
compile project(':unitygvr')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
compile files('libs/libprotobuf-java-nano.jar')
compile files('libs/support-annotations-23.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/unity-classes.jar')
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: please check `Related` section on your right side of the screen.

Comment: ok i will, thanks man!